# How to cast AnyObject? to String in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode6.3

Everything good until, I've downloaded the new version of Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2.

But when I compile my app again, a lots of error came out.  I've dealt with most  of them but there is a specific error that I couldn't figure it out the solutions

The error is "AnyObject? is not convertible to String?"

Before updating Xcode this was absolutely fine :

```
let firstName = self.currentUser["firstName"] as? String
```

Comment: try with as! for failable casts — Casts that can fail at runtime are now expressed with the new as! operator to make their potential for runtime failure clear to readers and maintainers of your code.

Comment: i tried!, didn't worked ;(

Answer (score 6):

i've figured out the solution

```
let firstName = self.currentUser?["firstName"] as? String
if let firstname = firstName {
     // Continue
} else {
    // Handling the error.
}
```

Comment: Beware, by using `!` instead of `?` in those two places, you are running the risk that if `currentUser` is ever `nil`, or if it doesn't have a value for `firstName`, then your app will crash.  You might want to consider `if let firstName = self.currentUser?["firstName"] as? String { ...use firstName... } else { ...optionally handle error... }`

Comment: ok i'll consider, but i my answer is it right
if yes please accept it